# Compare all text files in a directory, and sort by similarity

Tags: files, diff, text

In Unix, is there any way to compare every text file in a directory to every other text file in the directory, and then sort each pair of files by similarity (using the `diff` utility)? There are already some command-line Unix programs (such as fdupes) that can find duplicate files in a directory, but I'm wondering if it's possible to find similar files using a shell script as well.

Comment: It would probably be easier to compare one file to all other files in a directory. I'm still not sure how I'd sort the pairs of files by similarity, though.

Comment: Actually, I found a relevant search result just now. https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=sort+files+by+similarity&oq=sort+files+by+simi&gs_l=hp.3.0.33i29.116231.119931.1.120883.24.18.3.3.3.0.143.1789.11j7.18.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.YnwKYZVJZ38&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.dmQ&fp=a5c633476d088858&biw=1366&bih=572

Comment: I found a program called binsort that might be able to do this, but I haven't tested it yet. http://neoscientists.org/~tmueller/binsort/

Comment: Alternatively, I could simply obtain the Levenshtein distance for each pair of text files. Also, a list of string metrics can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metrics

Comment: Here's a related question (about finding the longest common subsequence on Unix): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383067/what-is-a-shell-command-to-find-the-longest-common-substring-of-two-strings-in-u

Comment: I found a working demo of the longest common subsequence (which can be edited online): https://tinker.io/bea4d

Comment: A plagiarism detector might work.

Comment: @Gilles Are any plagiarism detectors capable of sorting a group of files by similarity to another file?

Comment: Plagiarism detectors primarily sort a file by similarity to a group of files, so that's not too far off the mark. I have no practical experience with those, I don't know whether there's an existing one that has a nice UI to classify a bunch of texts à la gqview.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is too broad on so many levels. Term "difference" depends on type of data and its container: txt, mp3, avi, jpg. For each of them you need to execute their own processing methods. For instance, text or source code files may require only `diff` utility. Music, video and image files require fuzzy logic and computer learning algorithms.

Comment: By the way, for example [`geeqie`](http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/) image viewer has some algorithms for comparing images.

Comment: What I really want to do is group files by binary similarity - that's why I posted a link to binsort here.

Comment: Also, there is a program called `diff` which can be used to find the difference between two files. Also, I'm mainly concerned with text and source code files here.

Comment: Also, it would probably be easier to compare files of just one file type, instead of comparing files of all types. I think text files and source code files would probably be the easiest to compare.

Comment: I've narrowed down the question's scope to discuss only text files and source files, so the question is no longer too broad.